# How do I play Minecraft Pocket Edition with my niece on LAN?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My niece and I love playing Minecraft: Pocket Edition together, but since the new update (0.12.3) we can't seem to play it. How should I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! We need more details if we are going to be able to answer your question accurately. Do you get any errors? What happens when you try to connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the stuff I do when this happens, is to check if "Broadcast to LAN" is open. If it is not, open it on both iPads.

Make sure that your niece is connected on the same WiFi as you.

If this doesn't work then restart the iPads or close completely the app then re-open it.

Comment: Why assume that the OP is using an iPad? Pocket Edition is available for most portable tablets & phones (both Android & iOS).

Comment: @bob OP told he was using an iPad but it got edited.

Comment: I have restarted the app and they both have broadcast to lan and we r on the same wifi

Comment: Confirm my answer then!
Also, next time you attempt to ask something, make sure it hasn't been asked before.